# Is there a way to call toField on a list of variables?

Tags: haskell

I have this function where all `varX` are of type `Maybe Something`:

```
res <- execute cn "insert into users values ..." [ toField var1 
  , toField var2
  , toField var3 
  , toField var4
  ]
```

Can I simplify it with  or something similiar? I've tried this:

```
res <- execute cn "insert into my_table values ..." toField <$> [var1, var2, var3, var4]
```

It's probably because `toField` doesn't return a list? `toField` is from [posgresql-simple](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.0.0/candidate/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what `var1`…`var4` are for example

```
show <$> [Just 1, Just 'a',Just "a",Just 3.1415]
```

is incorrect because GHC cannot unify the types inside the list - despite after applying `show` everything is a `String`

on the other hand if you have

```
var1,var2,var3,var4 :: Maybe a
```

i.e. all of them have the same type (for some type `a` that is an instance of the class `ToField`), you can do

```
res <- execute cn "insert into my_table values ..." (toField <$> [var1, var2, var3, var4])
```

as @ChadGilbert already said.

Answer (score 4):

You need to explicitly send the values being mapped in as a single parameter to `execute`. You can wrap `toField <$> [var1, var2, var3, var4]` in parentheses or prefix with `$`

```haskell
res <- execute cn "insert into my_table values ..." $ toField <$> [var1, var2, var3, var4]
```